# How to locate custom html elements using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, svg, webdriver

I have the following html code

```
  <svg height="600" width="910" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  
   id="svgcontent" overflow="visible" x="910" y="600" viewBox="0 0 910 600">
    <g style="pointer-events:all">
      <text fill="rgb(0,0,0)" font-family="Sans-Serif" font-size="13" id="80-155-126" 
        transform="rotate(-90, 168, 126)" y="126" x="168" style="pointer-
         events:inherit">A100A</text>
   </g>
  </svg>
```

I tried in the following way but didnt get succeeded

```
assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' 
 and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' and @id='svgcontent']//*[local-
 name()='g' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']/text")).size(), 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following

```
assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and @id='svgcontent']//*[local-name()='text']")).size(), 1);
```

it should work, but

```
assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' and @id='svgcontent']//*[local-name()='g' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']/*[local-name()='text']")).size(), 1);
```

should be also ok.